# Larger file format icons?

Tags: 2013, file-icons

I found [this post](http://sharepoint.danishislam.com/Blog/Post/11/SharePoint-List-Type-Column-to-show-icon-based-on-file-type-attached) which shows how to get file icons for different types from **/_layouts/images/**.

This is good for little icons (16x16), but are larger icons stored somewhere? I'm not looking to change the icons or upload new ones. Just wondering if in a hidden folder somewhere are already lurking some 32x32 or 64x64. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an example of where these larger icons are presented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are larger images in there as well.  Are you on-prem?  If so, you can look through the folder to see if you can find what you want.

But if not, there are 32x32 icons that follow the same format as in the article you linked to, with the prefix "lg_", so for example:

`lg_icpptx.png`

`lg_icdoc.png`

Etc.

Comment: We are on prem, but I'm not the owner and have no access to the farm and navigating to the folder doesn't five me a directory listing. The secret was to prefix with lg_ I had been going the other way and trying _large and _lg. Thank you for

Comment: Unfortunately the `lg_iczip.png` is not provided my Microsoft.

Comment: you can also use 256_ic_xxx.png for a larger format (works in SP 2013 & online)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/purtuga/SPImages/ is the easiest tool
to browse around your Layouts images

Microsoft uses images from `formap32x32.png` (and others)
It is an imagemap/sprites layout

**BUT** Microsoft has changed the layout more than once over the past years, so it is not save to use the images yourself. Maybe the onces in the top-left are okay.

My first Angular project in 2013 was on a Viewer for formatmap32x32.png
http://www.engelman.nl/projects/stor/index.html
It made me fall in love with Angular, although that first project is a great example of abuse... but hey! it works :-)
Makes it easy to get the CSS config for the image sprites

The last comparison of Microsofts changes I did was august 2014
http://www.engelman.nl/projects/stor/formatmapdiff.html

http://www.engelman.nl/projects/stor/formatmap32x32_aug2014.png

Comment: Wow that is awesome. I love the sprite extractor and will book mark this for future use. Dylan's answer was more for my immediate needs.